# Apply filter after transformation

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-filters, drop-shadow

I have a transparent .png image of crossing lines. If the `drop-shadow` CSS `filter` is applied, only the lines drop shadow, not the bounding rect (it's not the same as `box-shadow`).

When I apply both `drop-shadow` filter and `transform: rotate`, Chrome and FF draw the shadow first, then rotate the resulting image (merged with the shadow). I want the rotated image to drop shadow instead. (As if there is a static light source, when the image rotates).

Is it possible in pure CSS?

The only solution I see is JS trigonometrical calculation of the shadow parameters every time the image rotates.

Regards,

Comment: please post a fiddle so we can understand better.

Comment: @geeksal https://jsfiddle.net/noober/mojLqept/1/

Comment: did you want the shadow to remain static in one place. I am just having the difficulty in understanding what you want. I think an image illustration will serve the purpose.

Comment: just realize is that jsfiddle using JS is what you want to achive using CSS. If yes than just post another jsfiddle with CSS code you have worked so far.

Comment: @geeksal Sorry, if the question is not clear enough. It's a matter of priorities. If you apply the filter before the transformation you will see a different result comparing to the transformation applied before the filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am quite sure that this question has been answered before, but couldn't find it, so here it goes:

set the filter on a base element, and apply the transform in the inner one

```css
.base {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 0px red);
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 0px red);
}

.element {
   animation: rotate 6s linear infinite;
  border: solid 3px green;
  border-top-left-radius: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
 }

@keyframes rotate {
  from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thank you! I was sure that an inner element would drop a boxed shadow.